# OptaPlanner benchmarking won't run

Tags: benchmarking, optaplanner

I'm trying to run an OptaPlanner benchmark with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plannerBenchmark xmlns="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/benchmark" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/benchmark https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/benchmark/benchmark.xsd">
    <benchmarkDirectory>data/acme</benchmarkDirectory>

    <inheritedSolverBenchmark>
        <solver>
            <solutionClass>org.acme.domain.Main</solutionClass>
            <entityClass>org.acme.domain.Standstill</entityClass>
            <entityClass>org.acme.domain.Visit</entityClass>
            <scoreDirectorFactory>
                <constraintProviderClass>org.acme.solver.MainConstraintProvider</constraintProviderClass>
                <initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN</initializingScoreTrend>
            </scoreDirectorFactory>
            <termination>
                <secondsSpentLimit>30</secondsSpentLimit>
            </termination>
        </solver>
        <problemBenchmarks>
            <solutionFileIOClass>org.acme.bootstrap.AcmeSolutionIO</solutionFileIOClass>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/latest.xml</inputSolutionFile>
        </problemBenchmarks>
    </inheritedSolverBenchmark>
    <solverBenchmark>
        <solver>
            <constructionHeuristic>
                <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
            </constructionHeuristic>
            <localSearch>
                <localSearchType>LATE_ACCEPTANCE</localSearchType>
            </localSearch>
        </solver>
    </solverBenchmark>
</plannerBenchmark>
```

However, I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.optaplanner.benchmark.api.PlannerBenchmarkException: Benchmarking failed: failureCount (1). The exception of the firstFailureSingleBenchmarkRunner (blankData_Config_0_0) is chained.
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmarkingEnded(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:326)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmark(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:100)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmarkAndShowReportInBrowser(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:424)
    at org.acme.bootstrap.BenchmarkApp.main(BenchmarkApp.kt:29)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The class (class java.lang.Long) should have a no-arg constructor to create a planning clone.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.lambda$retrieveCachedConstructor$0(FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.ConcurrentMemoization.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMemoization.java:44)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.retrieveCachedConstructor(FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java:85)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.FieldAccessingSolutionCloner$FieldAccessingSolutionClonerRun.constructClone(FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java:158)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.FieldAccessingSolutionCloner$FieldAccessingSolutionClonerRun.clone(FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java:150)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.FieldAccessingSolutionCloner$FieldAccessingSolutionClonerRun.process(FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java:207)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.FieldAccessingSolutionCloner$FieldAccessingSolutionClonerRun.processQueue(FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java:194)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.FieldAccessingSolutionCloner$FieldAccessingSolutionClonerRun.cloneSolution(FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java:136)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.cloneSolution(FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java:73)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.cloneSolution(AbstractScoreDirector.java:257)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.cloneWorkingSolution(AbstractScoreDirector.java:250)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.recaller.BestSolutionRecaller.updateBestSolutionAndFire(BestSolutionRecaller.java:129)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.phaseEnded(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:146)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.solve(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:98)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:99)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:192)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.call(SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.java:122)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.call(SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Long.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2754)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.lambda$retrieveCachedConstructor$0(FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java:88)
    ... 22 more
```

I've tried many other benchmark configs including with `<solverBenchmarkBluePrintType>CONSTRUCTION_HEURISTIC_WITH_AND_WITHOUT_LOCAL_SEARCH</solverBenchmarkBluePrintType>` but none of them work either.

I had it working previously, but I went back to it after a number of changes and it no longer works.

I'm using a `SimpleLongScore` now instead of a `SimpleScore` and I'm wondering if that has anything to do with the error since before it wasn't throwing this exception.

Any ideas?

**Edit #1:**
I wish I could provide more code, but I really don't know what code to include.

The bizarre thing is that OptaPlanner runs just fine through `mvn compile quarkus:dev`, but when I run my benchmark app, from the main entry, it gives the errors as mentioned before, `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The class (class java.lang.Long) should have a no-arg constructor to create a planning clone.`

Here's my main:

```
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val plannerBenchmarkFactory:PlannerBenchmarkFactory = PlannerBenchmarkFactory.createFromXmlResource("benchmarkBluePrintConfig.xml")
        val plannerBenchmark: PlannerBenchmark = plannerBenchmarkFactory.buildPlannerBenchmark()
        plannerBenchmark.benchmarkAndShowReportInBrowser()
    }
```

The `solverConfig.xml` can also be the same for both, but only the benchmark app throws the error. It's pretty odd to me.

Comment: `Long` instances are not expected to be cloned. It seems like you're using the `Long` type in some unexpected way so perhaps its instances leak into a collection that is being cloned. Please review that. If you can't fix it yourself, please share pieces of code where you use the `Long` type.

Comment: Thanks - I should mention that OptaPlanner is working fine for me through Quarkus. It's only when I try to run it as a benchmark that it does this. To be clear though, Ints can be cloned but not Longs? I'll have to try converting everything back to Ints I guess.

Comment: Switching to Integer won't help. Might you have a Long instance in a list annotated with `@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty`?

Comment: See edits. I have many ```Long``` instances with my ```Visit``` and ```SubShift``` (```PlanningVehicle``` equivalent) classes. From the OptaWeb Vehicle Routing example, there is ```private int capacity;``` in ```PlanningVehicle``` so I assume that's normal. Is that somehow the problem? I did try changing everything to ```Int``` and it didn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I figured it out.**

In my `Visit` class I was using a `@CustomShadowVariable`:

```
    @DeepPlanningClone
    @CustomShadowVariable(
        variableListenerClass = ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener::class,
        sources = [PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "previousStandstill")]
    )
    var arrivalTime: Long? = null
```

**Removing `@DeepPlanningClone` solved the problem.**

I have no idea why it runs fine when the `SolverManager` is `@Inject`'d as opposed to throwing the error when `SolverConfig`/`SolverManager` is created through the API (as it is in my Benchmark App).